# Disable stacking for 1 dataset

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have this following chart

[image]

They are stacked. I use this property in my options:

```
      scales: {
        y: {
          stacked: true,
        }
      },
```

How can i disable stacking for just 1 dataset? I want to disable stacking for the brown dataset so that the other charts fill it.

The brown chart is the summ of the 3 small charts. I want to deactivate the stacking for the big brown chart so i can see if my chart data is displaying correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the stacks in the datasets. If you assign all datasets to the same stack except for your brown one you get what you want:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'pink',
        stack: 'stack2'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'orange',
        stack: 'stack1'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
        borderColor: 'turquoise',
        stack: 'stack1'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        stacked: true
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```